# Remove commas from arrays located inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array, containing smaller arrays:

```
var fruits = [["Bananas", "2"], ["Apples", "4"], ["Oranges", "5"]];
```

I would like to display them like this, removing the comma inside the smaller arrays and adding a hyphen:

Bananas - 2

Apples - 4

Oranges - 5

I have tried the following, however it's still not working:

```js
var fruits = [
  ["Bananas", "2"],
  ["Apples", "4"],
  ["Oranges", "5"]
];
var fruitsToday = [];
for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  fruitsToday += fruits[i].join(" - ");
}
document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = fruitsToday.join("<br>");
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe replace `fruitsToday += fruits[i].join(" - ");` with `fruitsToday.push(fruits[i].join(" - "));`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit to add additional explanation and reading:

- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/
- https://dev.to/promhize/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascripts-implicit-coercion-e23
- https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-type-conversion
  *(ecma's table is the most accurate and concise to read, but its presentation may be a bit spartan to read.  I'll be honest I'm not satisfied with the bloggers' overly verbose explanations of implicit coercion either.)*

> **Implicit coercion is triggered by the binary + operator, when any
>   operand is a string**

You need to use an array and push to it.  Using the `+` operator will coerce the array into a string and concatenate the strings.

```js
var fruits = [["Bananas", "2"], ["Apples", "4"], ["Oranges", "5"]];
var fruitsToday = [];
  for (i=0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    fruitsToday.push(fruits[i].join(" - "));
  }
  document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = fruitsToday.join("<br>");
```

```html
<div id="today"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could map the joined items and use the array for the output.

```js
var fruits = [["Bananas", "2"], ["Apples", "4"], ["Oranges", "5"]],
    fruitsToday = fruits.map(a => a.join(' - '));

document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = fruitsToday.join('<br>');
```

```html
<div id="today"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be doable in one line :)

```js
var fruits = [["Bananas", "2"], ["Apples", "4"], ["Oranges", "5"]];

document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = fruits.map(f => f.join(" - ")).join("<br>");
```

```html
<span id="today"><span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works well. Problem is `fruitsToday.join("<br>");` because `fruitsToday` is string and `join()` works only with array.

```js
var fruits = [["Bananas", "2"], ["Apples", "4"], ["Oranges", "5"]];
var fruitsToday = [];
for (i=0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  fruitsToday += (fruits[i].join(" - ") + '<br/>');
}
document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = fruitsToday;
```

```html
<div id=today></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the implicit string concatenation between the array `fruitsToday` and the array at index `i` `->` `fruits[i]`.

```
fruitsToday += fruits[i].join(" - ");
            ^
```

Change that concatenation by the call of function `Array.prototype.push`

```js
let fruits = [
  ["Bananas", "2"],
  ["Apples", "4"],
  ["Oranges", "5"]
];
let fruitsToday = [];
for (let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  fruitsToday.push(fruits[i].join(" - "));
}
document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = fruitsToday.join("<br>");
```

```html
<div id="today"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the below using map() but creating the required new array "fruitsToday" with the new elements. You can then use the new array as you wish.

```js
var fruits = [["Bananas", "2"],  ["Apples", "4"],  ["Oranges", "5"]];
var fruitsToday = [];

fruits.map(function(e) {fruitsToday.push(e[0]+" - "+ e[1]);})

console.log(fruitsToday);
```